# ImportError: cannot import name 'image_dataset_from_directory' with TF-nightly-gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I knew 'image_dataset_from_directory' is available for tf-nightly, but I'm using GPU to train my data, so I installed tf-nightly-gpu, which seems doesn't support 'image_dataset_from_directory'?

Is there any way to use 'image_dataset_from_directory' with a gpu version of TF?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

instead of using "from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import image_dataset_from_directory"
use "from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory"